# GemfireTemplate workaround for Gemfire 9.0.1

Tags: apache, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

Is there currently a workaround for making use of GemfireTemplate class when upgrading to Gemfire 9.0.1?

One of the upgrade requirements is changing all referencing from:

com.gemstone.gemfire
to
org.apache.geode

However GemfireTemplate dosen't appear to have a corresponding apache geode subclass: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-gemfire/1.7.0.APACHE-GEODE-EA-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.html

Would it be possible to create a wrapper class to perform the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

There is a version of [GemfireTemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.0.M1/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.java) (i.e. [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.0.M1/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.java#L27-L37)) in *Spring Data GemFire* **2.0.x** (*Spring Data Release Train* [Kay](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Kay#participating-modules)), having a current **Milestone 1 release** (i.e. `org.springframework.data:spring-data-gemfire:2.0.0.M1` in the [Spring Repos](https://repo.spring.io/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/General/libs-milestone-local/org/springframework/data/spring-data-gemfire/2.0.0.M1); NOTE: Milestones and Release Candidates are not published to *Maven Central*), which is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.0.M1/pom.xml#L22) **Pivotal GemFire 9.0.0-beta.1**.

We are [about to release](https://spring-calendar.cfapps.io/) (see *April 3rd*, if the date sticks) *Spring Data Release Train Kay* Milestone 2, which will include *Spring Data GemFire* **2.0.0.M2**, which was [upgraded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.0.x/pom.xml#L21) to **Pivotal GemFire 9.0.2**.

As for **Apache Geode**, there is *Spring Data Geode* **1.0.0.INCUBATING-RELEASE** ([here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspring-data-geode)), which is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/1.0.0.APACHE-GEODE-INCUBATING-RELEASE/pom.xml#L25) **Apache Geode 1.0.0-incubating**, which has the same [GemfireTemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/1.0.0.APACHE-GEODE-INCUBATING-RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.java) ([this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/1.0.0.APACHE-GEODE-INCUBATING-RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/GemfireTemplate.java#L27-L37)) for Geode.

I am about to release *Spring Data Geode* **1.1.0.RELEASE**, which will be [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/apache-geode/pom.xml#L25) the relatively new **Apache Geode 1.1.0** (GA release, non-incubating).

All of the resources you need to know about are here...

1. *Spring Data GemFire* project page: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-gemfire/
2. *Spring Data GemFire* Wiki (Compatibility Matrix): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/wiki/Spring-Data-GemFire-to-GemFire-Version-Compatibility
3. *Spring Data Commons* Wiki (SD Release Trains; see right nav): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki
4. *Maven Central* (SD Geode): http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cspring-data-geode

-j

Comment: As a quick follow up question do you know when the schema will be added for any of the Spring Data Gemfire 2.X will be released to?:
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/gemfire/

Comment: Spring Data GemFire 2.x (SD Kay) will be released shortly after Spring Framework 5 goes GA, which is in June (June 20th to be exact... https://spring-calendar.cfapps.io, though that could shift slightly).  Since, more generally, SD Kay, and specifically, Spring Data GemFire (2.x) has a hard dependency on the core Spring Framework (5.x), it must wait for SF's GA.

Comment: looks like GemfireTemplate is restricted per region. It can only query/update the region which the template was created with. Why spring create a template with such limitation ? And what to do if I would like to query cross regions ?

Comment: Well, the idea is, you are supposed to create a `GemfireTemplate` per Region.  Part of the reason the template class is only tied to a single Region is to make it "Thread-safe" (which is guaranteed by the Spring container's initialization safety).  Technically, it is possible to "reset" the Region on the template since GemfireTemplate extends GemfireAccessor, but I don't recommend it!

Comment: I'd also add that the GemfireTemplate, like many data store specific templates (e.g. `MongoTemplate` in _Spring Data MongoDB_) follow the Template pattern, and are modeled after the `JdbcTemplate` in the core Spring Framework.  Typically, you do not change the "`DataSource`" that a particular instance of the `JdbcTemplate` is tied to, you simply create another `JdbcTemplate` with that `DataSource`.